# Removing space from the end of a list item in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have the following list and I want to remove the space form the end of the list items,
Only from the end not all spaces?

```
items = [' apple ', 'banana ', 'orange ']
```

Comment: Just out of interest, what do you want to happen if a string ends with *two* spaces? Do you want them both gone, or just the second one? And is it *just* spaces, or all whitespace (tabs, et cetera)?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a list comprehension here with `rstrip()`:

```py
items = [' apple ', 'banana ', 'orange ']
output = [x.rstrip() for x in items]
print(output)  # [' apple', 'banana', 'orange']
```

Comment: This is *probably* the one OP wants as it removes all whitespace at the end, not just a single space character. But I've asked for clarification just in case.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a new list and use list comprehension.
Iterate through each element, check if it has space at the end of the element.
If it does, remove it and append it to a new list.

```
items = [' apple ', 'banana ', 'orange ']
newList = [x[:-1] for x in items if x[-1] == ' ']
print(newList)
```

**output**

```
[' apple', 'banana', 'orange']
```